# can't increment Glib::ustring::iterator (getting "invalid lvalue in increment" compiler error)

Tags: c++, iterator, glib

in the following code:

```
int utf8len(char* s, int len)
{
 Glib::ustring::iterator p( string::iterator(s) );
 Glib::ustring::iterator e ( string::iterator(s+len) );
 int i=0;
    for (; p != e; p++) // ERROR HERE!
  i++;
 return i;
}
```

I get the compiler error on the `for` line, which is sometimes "invalid lvalue in increment", and sometimes "ISO C++ forbids incrementing a pointer of type etc... ".

Yet, the follwing code:

```
int utf8len(char* s)
{
 Glib::ustring us(s);
 int i=0;
    for (Glib::ustring::iterator p = us.begin(); p != us.end(); p++)
  i++;
 return i;

}
```

compiles and works fine.

according the Glib::ustring documentation and the include file, ustring iterator can be constructed from `std::string` iterator, and has `operator++()` defined. Weird?

---EDIT---

It gets "Curiouser and curiouser"! this code

```
int utf8len(string::iterator s, string::iterator e)
{
    Glib::ustring::iterator p(s);
    Glib::ustring::iterator end(e);
    int i=0;
    for (; p != end; p++)
        i++;
    return i;
}
```

compiles and works fine.

---EDIT---

**BONUS QUESTION :)**

Is there a difference in C++ between the 2 ways of defining a variable:

```
  classname ob1( initval );
  classname ob1 = initval;
```

I believed that they are synonymous; yet, if I change

```
   Glib::ustring::iterator p( string::iterator(s) );
```

to

```
 Glib::ustring::iterator p = string::iterator(s);
```

I get a compiler error (gcc 4.1.2)

> conversion from
>   ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator,
>   std::allocator > >’ to
>   non-scalar type
>   ‘Glib::ustring_Iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator,
>   std::allocator > > >’ requesed

thanks a lot!

Comment: "I get the compiler error... which is sometimes..."  If you post the exact code and the exact error message that it causes, it would make it much easier for people to help.

Comment: that's the point - I get different error messages at different compilations, which is quite weird in itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your declaration declares this function:

```
Glib::ustring::iterator p(string::iterator s);
```

The parentheses in your code around `s` are ignored. They are like the parentheses around `n` in the following example

```
int(n);
n = 0; /* n is actually an int variable! */
```

They are for grouping modifiers like pointer (`*`) or references (`&`) (think about `void(*fptr)()`). In your case the parentheses are just semantically redundant.

Try this one instead:

```
Glib::ustring::iterator p( (string::iterator(s)) );
```

The parentheses introduced make the compiler regognize that it should instead construct an object `p` initialized from an expression (because a function parameter declaration can't have parentheses around it, it's not parsed as a parameter declaration, but instead as an initializer).

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
why wouldn't the version "Glib::ustring::iterator p = string::iterator(s);" work, though? Seems that it does not have this ambiguity.

Comment: @davka in an initialization, only one user defined conversion is allowed and in that form only non-explicit copy constructors are used. Any of these two facts could cause the compile error.